# How to dynamically display moment date in React

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am new to React. I am trying to create a week by week scroller for an eventual calendar that changes the week as you hit forward or back arrow buttons. The dates change as I hope in console logs, but I can't figure out how to get the date that is displaying to change as the user hits the buttons. I am confused by whether to use state, props, etc. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var week_nav = React.createClass({


 render: function() {
    var currentWeekStart = moment().startOf('week').format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    var currentWeekEnd = moment().endOf('week').format("MM/DD/YYYY");

var prevWeek = function() {
  newStart = currentWeekStart.slice();
  newEnd = currentWeekEnd.slice();
  newWeekStart = moment(newStart).subtract(7, 'days').format("MM/DD/YYYY");
  newWeekEnd = moment(newEnd).subtract(7, 'days').format("MM/DD/YYYY");
  currentWeekStart = newWeekStart;
  currentWeekEnd = newWeekEnd;
}

var upcomingWeek = function() {
  newStart = currentWeekStart.slice();
  newEnd = currentWeekEnd.slice();
  newWeekStart = moment(newStart).add(7, 'days').format("MM/DD/YYYY");
  newWeekEnd = moment(newEnd).add(7, 'days').format("MM/DD/YYYY");
  currentWeekStart = newWeekStart;
  currentWeekEnd = newWeekEnd;
}

return (
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col s2">
      <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="prevWeek" onClick={prevWeek}><i className="material-icons">arrow_back</i></a>
    </div>
    <div className="col s4">
      <p>{currentWeekStart} - {currentWeekEnd}</p>
    </div>
    <div className="col s2">
      <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="upcomingWeek" onClick={upcomingWeek}><i className="material-icons">arrow_forward</i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
)
  }
});
```

Comment: Props is for passing initial values, state is for something that is stateful, such as the date of a scroller because it changes date when scrolled up or down. You could print a state object and simply update the state when the scroll button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the state to keep the current week end and start. Components re-render whenever props or state change. You need to keep this data in the state (if using redux you will get the data from the props).

Here's an example using ES6 (Make sure to include babel with stage-0 in your webpack config):

```
class WeekNav extends PureComponent {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      currentWeekStart: moment().startOf('week').format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
      currentWeekEnd: moment().endOf('week').format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
    });
  }

  prevWeek = () => {
    const { currentWeekStart, currentWeekEnd } = this.state;

    newStart = currentWeekStart.slice();
    newEnd = currentWeekEnd.slice();
    newWeekStart = moment(newStart).subtract(7, 'days').format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    newWeekEnd = moment(newEnd).subtract(7, 'days').format("MM/DD/YYYY");

    this.setState({
      currentWeekStart: newWeekStart,
      currentWeekEnd: newWeekEnd,
    });
  }

  upcomingWeek = () => {
    const { currentWeekStart, currentWeekEnd } = this.state;

    newStart = currentWeekStart.slice();
    newEnd = currentWeekEnd.slice();
    newWeekStart = moment(newStart).add(7, 'days').format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    newWeekEnd = moment(newEnd).add(7, 'days').format("MM/DD/YYYY");

    this.setState({
      currentWeekStart: newWeekStart,
      currentWeekEnd: newWeekEnd,
    });
  }

 render: function() {
    const { currentWeekStart, currentWeekEnd } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col s2">
          <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="prevWeek" onClick={this.prevWeek}><i className="material-icons">arrow_back</i></a>
        </div>
        <div className="col s4">
          <p>{currentWeekStart} - {currentWeekEnd}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col s2">
          <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="upcomingWeek" onClick={this.upcomingWeek}><i className="material-icons">arrow_forward</i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

PS: It'd be quite easy to update my previous code to ES5 using `React.createClass`.

Comment: Thank you! Since i am using es5 mine ended up looking a little different but i did:

...
  getInitialState() {
    return {
    currentWeekStart: moment().startOf('week').format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
    currentWeekEnd: moment().endOf('week').format("MM/DD/YYYY")
    }
  },
...
    var prevWeek = function() {
      newStart = currentWeekStart.slice();
...      
      this.setState({
        currentWeekStart: currentWeekStart,
        currentWeekEnd: currentWeekEnd
      });
    }.bind(this)

Comment: I have found learning React to be more difficult for m than some other frameworks like Angular2. React seems to be taking a fundamentally different approach. Given that my project is in ES5, do you have any resources you recommend? I have found it hard to find ES5 examples.